# Delphi - how to get a list of all files of directory

Tags: delphi, opendialog

I am working with delphi, I want a list of all files of a directory when I execute openpicturedialog.

> i.e., When open dialog is executed and
>   i select one file from it, I want the
>   list of all files from the directory
>   of selected file.

You can even suggest me for getting directory name from `FileName` property of `TOpenDialog`
Thank You.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

@Himadri, the primary objective of the OpenPictureDialog is not select an directory, anyway if you are using this dialog with another purpose you can try this code.

```
Var
  Path    : String;
  SR      : TSearchRec;
  DirList : TStrings;
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Path:=ExtractFileDir(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName); //Get the path of the selected file
    DirList:=TStringList.Create;
    try
          if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faArchive, SR) = 0 then
          begin
            repeat
                DirList.Add(SR.Name); //Fill the list
            until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
            FindClose(SR);
          end;

     //do your stuff

    finally
     DirList.Free;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: I think your code needs a try finally protecting FindFirst/FindClose(SR).

Comment: found a bug you need to replace 
if FindFirst('*.*', faArchive, SR) = 0 then
with
if FindFirst(Path+'*.*', faArchive, SR) = 0 then

because it doesn't look at the path

Comment: How to sort the list by the date of the files ?

Comment: FindFirst is quite outdated. Why not TDirectory.GetFiles ?

Comment: this code problem in win10

Answer (score 56):

If you're using Delphi 2010 then you can use [**TDirectory.GetFiles**](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles).

First add `UIUtils` to your `uses` clause, then use the following in your event handler (in addition to code you already have in that event handler):

```
uses IOUtils;

var
   path: string;
begin
   for Path in TDirectory.GetFiles(OpenPictureDialog1.filename)  do
      Listbox1.Items.Add(Path); // assuming OpenPictureDialog1 is the name you gave to your OpenPictureDialog control
end;
```

Comment: Good option but I am not using delphi 2010... :-(

Comment: Don't forget to include : uses IOUtils;

Comment: TDirectory.GetFiles accepts an additional argument (the first one is the folder) with file mask, were one can get files e.g. with certain extension or matching certain pattern in the filename.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE4 (still!) and TDirectory is available.

Answer (score 3):

Change the *filter* property in your OpenPictureDialog to include all files:

```
All (*.*)
```

**Edit**: I don't think you can select a directory in a Open(Picture)Dialog, it surely isn't the purpose of an OpenPictureDialog anyway.

Then use [FindFirst](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindFirst) and [FindNext](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindNext) to get the files in this dir.

Comment: I am not selecting a directory but a file.. and I want other file list of parent directory of selected file.. read the question carefully...

Comment: In that case, CaldonCZE has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extractFilePath function to get the directory name:

```
myPath := extractFilePath(FileName);
```

where FileName is name of file you choose by OpenDialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then  
  FileListBox1.Directory := extractFilePath(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
```

You can also use a FilterComboBox linked to FileListBox to filter the file type.

TFileListBox and TFilterComboBox are in the tool palette under "Win 3.1". From Delphi 4 there are these objects.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can get the "path" information of the files in the folder you want. You can use Delphi's `System.IOUtils` library for this.

```
uses 
...
 System.IOUtils;
...

var List : TStringlist;
var File : String := '';
var Path : string := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Edit1.Text);

Lista := TStringList.Create;
try
    for File in TDirectory.GetFiles(Path) do
        List.Add(File); // Add all file names to list
finally
    FreeAndNil(Lista);
end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).