# No Disk Error c0000013 76b6b7c

Tags: windows, delphi, pascal

I'm writing an application in `Delphi`. Its a file browser with copying, delete etc. for school project. When app is detecting removable devices, and I'm trying to copy file to one of them.
I'm getting `c0000013` error with parameters `76b6b7c 4 76b6b7c 76b6b7c`.

I read that changing value `ErrorMode` to 2 fixes it. Yes it fixes but i can't change this variable directly from `Delphi` app. I know that one usb is usb ghost, but i don't know how to hide this one usb or skip it. I can't even check that because of this error.

Any other idea to fix it from app if it's needed ?

Comment: Although it's a system global setting, MS shows where you turn off "system hard error message dialog box" in possibility of it popping up in an unattended environment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128642/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Error `c0000013` means that there is no (readable) media the in location that you're accessing.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As such it is perfectly ok to check for the error and move on if there's no media.

You can get a list of all USB devices like so (see: [Delphi - How to get list of USB removable hard drives and memory sticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718192/delphi-how-to-get-list-of-usb-removable-hard-drives-and-memory-sticks))

```
procedure GetUsbDrives(List: TStrings);
var
  DriveBits: set of 0..25;
  I: Integer;
  Drive: AnsiChar;
begin
  List.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Cardinal(DriveBits) := GetLogicalDrives;

    for I := 0 to 25 do
      if I in DriveBits then
      begin
        Drive := Chr(Ord('a') + I);
        if GetBusType(Drive) = BusTypeUsb then
          List.Add(Drive);
      end;
  finally
    List.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

If you then access the drive and get the error, simply use a try-except to dectect if any problems occur, see: [Delphi - how to get a list of all files of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027561/delphi-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-of-directory)

```
function IsDevicePresent(DriveLetterOrPath: string): boolean;
const 
  success = 0;
  Win_DeviceIsPresent = true;
  Fail_DeviceNotPresent = false;
var 
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  Drive: string;
begin
  Drive:= ExtractFileDrive(DriveLetterOrPath);
  try
    Result:= (FindFirst(Drive, faAnyFile, SearchRec) = success);
  except 
    Result:= Fail_DeviceNotPresent;
  end; {try}
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it didn't helps, if i check each of pendrive connected, by    if IsDevicePresent(drive) = TRUE
 then 
for ex. copying
There is no error, but simply do not copy file on any of connected usb i chose.

Comment: @MalcolmCartney, of course it does not copy, that's the whole point of the code, You cannot copy to a stick that gives errors. That's obvious. Either the stick is damaged, or your windows needs a driver update.

Comment: But i mean that, now i can't copy even on the properly working usb flash. It always gives False i think.

Comment: Then you'll need to tweak the code a bit until it works the way you want.